# Copying huge partitioned My_ISAM table into a single innoDB table

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I have a huge My_ISAM table "msg_c_total" which is actually partitioned into "msg_c_1" to "msg_c_200". I want to make an innoDB copy of "msg_c_total" with a new name. I cannot still alter the original table (and change it to innoDB) because some of the stored procedures still work on the partitioned tables.

I created a new innoDB table (with just one index to avoid slowdowns during insert). I then used the following command. After 30 minutes, the query is still running and there is no records in the new table. The MySQL is also gradually becoming unresponsive.

```
INSERT into msg_new SELECT * FROM msg_c_total
```

1- Does Percona tools offer something to make the copy (hopefully does it gradually to avoid severe slowdowns on the server).

2- Is there a way to run the above "insert into" gradually (and automatically without adding ranges to the select command).

Thanks.

Server config:

```
ft_min_word_len         =3

connect_timeout         =15
join_buffer_size        =4M
key_buffer_size         =6G
max_allowed_packet      =2M
max_connections         =2600
max_connect_errors      =30
myisam_sort_buffer_size =528M
read_buffer_size        =4M
read_rnd_buffer_size    =4M
sort_buffer_size        =4M
table_cache             =512
thread_cache_size       =256
thread_concurrency      =16
wait_timeout            =120
max_tmp_tables          =512
tmp_table_size          =512M
max_heap_table_size     =512M
interactive_timeout     =1800
query_cache_type        =1
query_cache_size        =512M
skip-external-locking
skip-name-resolve
myisam-recover          =FORCE,BACKUP
concurrent_insert       =2
open-files              =30000
event_scheduler=ON
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_data_home_dir            = /app/mysql
innodb_data_file_path           = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 30G
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 256M
innodb_log_file_size            = 1256M
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 64M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 2
innodb_lock_wait_timeout        = 50
innodb_table_locks              = 0
innodb_support_xa               = 0
innodb_thread_concurrency       = 16
skip-innodb_doublewrite
innodb_buffer_pool_restore_at_startup = 1

long_query_time                 = 3
```

Comment: Can you include the table size? Do you have triggers on this table? What MySQL version? Is `msg_c_total` being modified? Have you given innodb a large buffer pool to work with? Do you have any replication from or to this server?

Comment: How big is "big"?

Comment: @danback it is around 0.5 terabytes (200 million records).  There are no triggers for reading from the old table and there is no triggers on the new one. The buffer is 1G. Is that enough? There is no replication right now.

Comment: How much RAM?  Which version of MySQL?  (There may be some tricks to play.)

Answer (score 1):

MyISAM only locks the entire table.  That `SELECT` is blocking *all* writes.

By partitioning do you mean "PARTITION BY..." and `msg_c_1` is a *partition* name?  Or is `msg_c_1` a table name and you are using code to pick the appropriate *table*?

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; there are many subtitles to check on.

What is the "table" partitioned by?

200 is a rather large number of partitions.

What is the `PRIMARY KEY`?  Are there any `UNIQUE` keys?

I *may* recommend something like http://localhost/rjweb/mysql/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks for doing the copy in chunks.  (Ignore 'delete' and 'update'; focus on the chunking.)  However, since the PK is not clustered with the data in MyISAM, some of the performance won't be available.

How much RAM?  What are the settings of `key_buffer_size` and `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  See http://localhost/rjweb/mysql/doc.php/memory for what to do when using both Engines.